# Primefaces Dialog not working with Chrome

Tags: jsf, primefaces, dialog

I have a p:dialog. My intention is to create a list using p:datagrid and when user clicks an item this dialog will open and show its details. Please consider the example of p:datagrid in the showcase. However, currently it works fine in IE but not in Chrome. If I define "modal=true" then the browser turns black but the dialog doesn't show up.

```
<p:commandButton update=":form:sharePanel" value="Share" style="font-size: 10px" oncomplete="PF('dlg').show()" rendered="false">
                                <f:setPropertyActionListener target="#{shareController.current}" value="#{status}" />
                            </p:commandButton>

<p:dialog widgetVar="dlg" resizable="false" id="sharePanel" styleClass="no-border" modal="true">  
                <h:outputText value="#{shareController.current.url.url}" /> 
                <h:panelGrid columns="3">                            
                    <p:dataGrid value="#{shareController.current.url.NLinkList}" var="nshare" columns="1" rendered="#{shareController.current.url.NLinkList.size() > 0}">
                        <h:panelGroup styleClass="tag noun">
                            <h:outputText value="#{nshare.noun}" />
                        </h:panelGroup>
                    </p:dataGrid>
                    <p:dataGrid value="#{shareController.current.url.VLinkList}" var="vshare" columns="1" rendered="#{shareController.current.url.VLinkList.size() > 0}">
                        <h:panelGroup styleClass="tag verb">
                            <h:outputText value="#{vshare.verb}" />
                        </h:panelGroup>
                    </p:dataGrid>
                    <p:dataGrid value="#{shareController.current.url.PLinkList}" var="pshare" columns="1" rendered="#{shareController.current.url.PLinkList.size() > 0}">
                        <h:panelGroup styleClass="tag prep">
                            <h:outputText value="#{pshare.prep}" />
                        </h:panelGroup>                    
                    </p:dataGrid>
                </h:panelGrid>
            </p:dialog>
```

What is wrong here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are using Primefaces versions before 4.0 use `dlg.show()` instead of `PF('dlg').show()`.

And try appending the dialog in body using attribute `appendToBody="true"`, because if the Facelet is more complex and if you are using Layouts the dialog won't fire ind some browsers only model will appear.

```
<p:dialog appendToBody="true" >
```

Comment: Turned out that if I move the entire code inside a h:body element the dialog would then show up. still trying to figure out why. Thanks for the suggestions and I give you the best answer

Comment: The statement *" because sometime if Primefaces js fis not included then the PF function will be loaded."* is a completely wrong explanation of the cause.